# Nesting a webpart within another webpart

Tags: c#, asp.net, nested, web-parts, kentico

Does anyone know if there is a way within Kentico CMS to nest a webpart within another webpart? I did a little research and I don't see many results on the topic so it seems the short answer is no, but maybe there is a workaround? On the project I am working on it is a requirement that the content author is able to place a hamburger menu on the page and then add other content within that hamburger menu via drag and drop. How can this be achieved within Kentico?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Circling back to this post. Although adding a `<cms:CMSEditableRegion />` tag to the page did indeed allow me to nest a Widget within a Webpart zone, it seemed a bit unnecessary for the user to have to switch between the design tab and page tab in order to achieve adding a nested component, not to mention having to register every webpart as a widget; quite unnecessary. I noticed Kentico's built in Layout webpart allowed for nested webparts so I looked at the code and was finally able to figure out how to implemented nesting a webpart within another webpart!

Ensure your webpart's code-behind inherits from **CMSAbstractLayoutWebPart**

Add the following method to your code-behind:

```
protected override void PrepareLayout()
{
    StartLayout();

    Append("<div");
    Append(" style=\"width: ", "100%", "\"");

    if (IsDesign)
    {
        Append(" id=\"", ShortClientID, "_env\">");

        Append("<table class=\"LayoutTable\" cellspacing=\"0\" style=\"width: 100%;\">");

        if (ViewModeIsDesign())
        {
            Append("<tr><td class=\"LayoutHeader\" colspan=\"2\">");

            // Add header container
            AddHeaderContainer();

            Append("</td></tr>");
        }

        Append("<tr><td id=\"", ShortClientID, "_info\" style=\"width: 100%;\">");
    }
    else
    {
        Append(">");
    }

    // Add the tabs
    var acc = new CMSAccordion();
    acc.ID = ID + "acc";
    AddControl(acc);

    if (IsDesign)
    {
        Append("</td>");

        if (AllowDesignMode)
        {
            // Width resizer
            Append("<td class=\"HorizontalResizer\" onmousedown=\"" + GetHorizontalResizerScript("env", "Width", false, "info") + " return false;\">&nbsp;</td>");
        }

        Append("</tr>");
    }

    // Pane headers
    string[] headers = TextHelper.EnsureLineEndings("HEADER", "\n").Split('\n');

    // Create new pane
    var pane = new CMSAccordionPane();
    pane.ID = ID + "pane";

    pane.Header = new TextTransformationTemplate(string.Empty);
    acc.Panes.Add(pane);

    pane.WebPartZone = AddZone(ID + "-ContentArea", ID + "-ContentArea", pane.ContentContainer);

    acc.SelectedIndex = 1;

    if (IsDesign)
    {
        if (AllowDesignMode)
        {
            Append("<tr><td class=\"LayoutFooter cms-bootstrap\" colspan=\"2\"><div class=\"LayoutFooterContent\">");

            // Pane actions
            Append("<div class=\"LayoutLeftActions\">");
            Append("</div></div></td></tr>");
        }

        Append("</table>");
    }
    Append("</div>");

    FinishLayout();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically a web part consists of user controls and not nested web parts.  Take a look at the CMSRepeater for instance.  It sets properties of a user control created by Kentico.

For what you're explaining it seems like you want a custom web part with widget zones in it.  Those widget zones will allow you to drag and drop content in place (what content I have no idea really because you can't drag and drop content in Kentico, only areas/widgets).

For navigation, you might want to look at creating it based on the content tree but maybe a hamburger menu is not for navigation in your case.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add a widget zone within the web-part.